# May I borrow the question/answer editing/preview gadgets?

Tags: support, etiquette, user-interface, editing

That is, I really like the feel and responsiveness of these gadgets (much better than LyX, for instance) and would like to use them offline.  Is this actually possible?  Are there licensing issues?

Cheers,

Comment: See also [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).

Comment: Isn't that nifty! I would guess, though I can't tell, that that one uses html5 "web" storage? However, it emphatically doesn't work "offline" in the sense I'm wanting.

Comment: I take back the second bit; it's on github https://github.com/benweet/stackedit and unpacks lively enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, [the editor and preview components are open source](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/). It's released under the MIT license which is one of the most permissive copyleft licenses in existence.

You'd need to make your own customized bits, but it wouldn't be entirely difficult to have it work entirely from local storage. If you come up with anything neat, feel free to share it :)